# Nativescript android shadows workaround

Tags: android, nativescript, shadow, nativescript-vue, box-shadow

I need some nice soft shadows. Android elevation system seams quite limited in NativeScript, or did i missed something? I need to have some more control, shadow opacity and spread radius especially. Or if there is no easy way, could you please recommend any workaround? Android is currently more important for me. Thanks!

Comment: You may directly access the native apis on the native element to gain more control over shadow.

Comment: @Manoj Thanks. Could you please tell me how? Or a link where i can read this?

Comment: Read about [Java to JS](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/marshalling/java-to-js), refer official Android documentation for whatever additional control you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Since NativeScript 5.4 we have androidElevation. The feature is currently only available on Android, hence the name.

The androidElevation is an implementation of Material Designs elevation. To use it you just set the elevation and give your view a backgroundColor and a margin (and a borderRadius if you like that).

```
<Label 
  id="label" 
  text="Shadow Games"

  margin="10"
  borderRadius="20"
  androidElevation="12"
  backgroundColor="white"/>
```

[reference here for iOS and android](https://dev.to/mudlabs/shadows-in-nativescript-2di9)